# Same variable name in Data types

Tags: haskell

Why using data types I cannot give same inner attribute name for those Data attributes?

Here I cannot reuse the variable name `val` in several Data

Does not compile

```
data Product = Product {val::String}deriving (Show, Eq)
data Price = Price {val::Double}deriving (Show, Eq)
data Discount = Discount { val::Double }deriving (Show, Eq)
```

compile

```
data Product = Product {productVal::String}deriving (Show, Eq)
data Price = Price {priceVal::Double}deriving (Show, Eq)
data Discount = Discount { discountVal::Double }deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Comment: Because you create a function `val :: Product -> String`, but in the next line you thus construct another function `val :: Price -> Double`. there is however an extension to allow this: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields

Comment: Thanks, I forgot everything in Haskell is a function!, but in this case it makes my code soooo verbose, it makes you almost desire not to type primitives. But that hack that you link is recommendable or is going against of the Pure functional code?. If it is what it is I can accept that verbosity

Comment: Indeed, record fields have this issue in Haskell -- this is probably one of the aspects I dislike the most. The issue can be mitigated a bit with `DuplicateRecordFields`, which lets you use duplicates and `val (... :: Product)` and `(p :: Product) { val = ... }`. Not very good, but not unusable either. Note that type annotations here are in general required, to solve ambiguity. I'd wish that GHC used type inference here, but alas, this is not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why using data types I cannot give same inner attribute name for those Data attributes?

If you define a record type, you implicitly have constructed a "getter". If you define a record datatype like:

```
data Product = Product { val :: String } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

then Haskell will construct a function:

```
val :: Product -> String
```

that obtains the `val` of a given `Product` object.

If you then later define a new record datatype:

```
data Price = Price { val :: Double } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

then you thus define two versions of `val`, which thus results in name clashes.

## The `DuplicateRecordFields` extension

The *Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC)* has, since 8.0.1, an extension [**`DuplicateRecordFields`**](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/glasgow_exts.html#duplicate-record-fields) that allows to specify two record datatypes with the same field name.

There is no problem to use the same record name for pattern matching, or when we construct records, for example:

```
productToPrice :: Product -> Price
productToPrice (Product {val = x}) = Price { val = 3 }
```

creates no problems, since `val` in `Product { val = x }` clearly refers to the `val` defined in the `Product` data constructor, and `val` in `Price { val = 3 }` refers to the `val` of the `Price` data constructor.

If we however use `val` as a function, it will create ambiguity:

```
Prelude> val (Product "foo")

<interactive>:15:1: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘val’
    It could refer to either the field ‘val’,
                             defined at <interactive>:1:25
                          or the field ‘val’, defined at <interactive>:2:21
```

We can add the signature of the function to specify which `val` we want to use:

```
Prelude> (val :: Product -> String) (Product "foo")
"foo"
```

or by specifying the type of `Product "foo"`, we obtain the same effect:

```
Prelude> val (Product "foo" :: Product)
"foo"
```

Given `val` however has the same type, or has some generic meaning, it might be better to introduce a typeclass, and thus define the `val` function there.

Comment: Great explanation. I use type class a lot, but for this particular case it feels too much does not it?.

Comment: @paul: yes, furthermore it looks like `val` of `Product` is not the same as `val` of `Price`, so then it is not very sensical to use a typeclass.

Comment: The very last example can be shortened a bit using `val (Product "foo" :: Product)`.